# python-memcached : Unable to memcache a mysql output. ( UnpickleableError: Cannot pickle objects )

Tags: python, python-2.7, memcached, mod-wsgi, wsgi

For some reason memcache does not seem to like

```
result
```

in this following code

```
db.query("select * from TABLE order by ID desc limit 70")
result = db.store_result()
m.set('1',result,60)
```

This is the error in apache error_log:

```
m.set('1',result,60)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/memcache.py", line 466, in set
return self._set("set", key, val, time, min_compress_len)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/memcache.py", line 639, in _set
store_info = self._val_to_store_info(val, min_compress_len)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/memcache.py", line 615, in _val_to_store_info
pickler.dump(val)
UnpickleableError: Cannot pickle objects
```

Something is probably going on with the "result".

otherwise instead of "result".. something else such as..

```
 m.set('1','test',60)
```

works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`store_result` instructs MySQL to store the result of your query locally, and returns a reference to that "result object". It does not actually return a list of rows.

To actually get the rows:

```
rows = result.fetch_row(maxrows=0)  # Actually fetches all the rows
m.set('1', rows, 60)
```

Now, it'd be best to instantiate a cursor than to use `_mysql` directly.